# I can not find the right font for the logo

Tags: font-identification, logo

I have problem to find similar or same font for this logo's. I try arround 200 fonts to match with this and I have not success. Problem is that letter "S" not match to all fonts what I have. I trying on google but not success. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [Microgramma Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/microgramma/d-bold-extended/) font? S pretty similar...

[image]